# Почему все пишут приложения на WinForms если WPF лучше?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Очень часто на этом форуме встречаются вопросы которые начинаются таким образом

> Я пишу приложение на WinForms. [...]

Я лично пробовал писать на Win Form и на WPF, и, как мне показалось, WPF более точный, более красивый в плане дизайна UI элементов. К тому же, в комплекте в WPF идёт замечательнейший язык Xaml, с которым работать намного легче чем с **C#** кодом внутри WinForms.

В связи с этим и задаюсь вопросом: какие преимущества есть у Win Form перед WPF и почему многие пишут на Win Form, хотя у них устарелый дизайн и они не поддерживаются?

Comment: Спрашивайте тех, кто пишет на винформах.

Comment: Мне кажется тут удобство и дело привычки. У меня знакомый есть, до сих пор не может вникнуть в WPF, он для него не понятный, не удобный... Когда для меня наоборот все, я в WPF могу натворить по дизайну такое, что вряд ли когда либо сделаю на WinForm. Так же как не крути, приложения на WPF более требовательны к ресурсам компьютера, а иногда этого просто не требуется, "Долой красоту, главное что бы стабильно и быстро работало". Скажем какой нибудь софт для бухгалтерии или чего подобного.

Comment: Пишут на WPF, ещё как, и больше, чем на WinForms. [По метке WinForms](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winforms?sort=newest&pageSize=30) 1565 вопросов, а [по метке WPF](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpf) 2270. Выводы делайте сами.

Comment: Кто-то ещё пишет на WinForms?! Я последний раз видел WinForms в 2010 году. И то уже тогда был WPF и все задумывались о том чтобы на него перейти.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

У WPF и правда масса преимуществ перед WinForms. Особенно серьёзным преимуществом я бы назвал понятие привязки (`Binding`) и `DataContext`, которые радикально облегчают написание правильно структурированных программ, в которых представление отделено от модели, бизнес-логики и контента.

(Не то, чтобы на WinForms невозможно было писать правильно, это намного сложнее, и требует ручной работы.)

Но следствием этого и обратной стороной является гораздо более высокая сложность WPF как фреймворка, намного более высокий *порог вхождения* в WPF и в правильные методики программирования на нём. Ведь сила WPF проявляется именно когда вы начинаете отделять контент от представления, без этого он ненамного лучше WinForms.

Тем, у кого есть опыт программирования на MFC или похожих UI-фреймворках, намного легче перейти на практически аналогичный WinForms, чем учить новые (хотя бы и более удобные и продуктивные) концепции, которые помогают лёгкому, удобному программированию на WPF.

Думаю, именно это является основной причиной того, что WinForms всё ещё существует.

Comment: Многие когда-то программировали формочки мышкой в VB 5, VB 6, Delphi 3, Delphi 7, поэтому им WinForms сразу знаком, понятен и привычен

Comment: @Андрей В WinForms можно так же программировать.

Comment: @Андрей Именно. Абсолютно все ранние гуёвые фреймворки — тонкие обёртки на стандартными виндовыми контролами, которые существовали с версии Windows 1.0. Поэтому они все похожи как две капли воды. Со временем гуёвые фреймворки обрастали концепциями, которые не существуют в стандартных контролах (у тех даже нет выравнивания), но далеко они не уходили. WPF же — революционный шаг вперёд, принципиально иной подход к построению интерфейса. Пользоваться им "как WinForms" практически невозможно. Из-за этой пропасти всем лень.

Comment: Но ведь и на Windows Forms гораздо удобнее программировать, используя привязки, а не только события. Но это удобнее далеко не в любой задаче. Поэтому никаких преимуществ у WPF нет, просто эту технологию больше пиарят. Поэтому WPF чисто для модников, для которых практичность не на первом месте.

Comment: @Modus: Мне не кажется, что преимуществ у WPF реально нету. DataContext, позволяющий автоматизировать привязки, DataTemplate в ресурсах, позволяющий динамически выбирать UI по типу VM, возможность составлять списки с произвольным шаблоном элемента, конвертеры, привязки элементов друг к другу через конвертер, стили (!), возможность подменить шаблон у любого (!) элемента и положить контентом не текст, а произвольный кусок UI (например, внутрь кнопки или пункта меню) — это не убийственные преимущества? Для всего, сложнее чем одна-кнопка-и-одна-таблица, WinForms не кажется мне хорошим выбором.

Comment: @VladD не говоря уже о том, что WPF тупо быстрее рендерится, чем WinForms :)

Comment: @tym32167: Ну да, всё же обертка над DirectX. А если уж хочется странного (полупрозрачность, например, или там засунуть в элемент списка целый мир), то без WPF вообще никак.

Comment: @VladD Я тут почитал комменты к другим ответам тоже. Жалко я пропустил эти ответы 3 года назад, я как раз тогда и с DataGrid работал, и с виртуализацией и кастомной виртуализацией, и с фокусами и все это было большое бизнес приложение и мы даже юзали местами встаивание WinForms контролов внутрь WPF, но это от того, что WinForms контролы были самопиным легаси шлаком, который никто переписывать не хотел.

Comment: Где это WPF быстрее рендерится? В рекламных материалах с сайте Microsoft?

Comment: @Modus: На более-менее современных машинах, как мне казалось, WPF быстрее. У вас есть другие наблюдения? (386DX и Pentium 2 оставим за бортом)

Answer (score 8):

Не знаю как другие, но лично я не помню тот момент когда последний раз использовал WinForms, если десктоп - лишь только WPF и как бы высокопарно это не звучало, в этой среде он до сих пор впереди планеты всей. При этом не важно, это кровавый enterprise или приложение с "бабочками и цветочками".

- Декларативное программирование, web подобная модель компоновки.
- Независимость от разрешающей способности, аппаратное ускорение, поддержка мультисенсорного ввода.
- Стили, триггеры, шаблоны, анимация, аудио и видео, команды, мощная система привязки, маршрутизируемые события.
- Продвинутые возможности для рисования.
- Приложения со страничной организацией.

и куча всего. Кроме того идеи, принципы и философия, которые положены в основу данной технологии, мне очень импонируют, близки и симпатичны. При этом я не являюсь каким-то ярым противником WinForms или фанатиком WPF, но просто если на секунду вдуматься и поразмыслить чего бы стоило сделать на "формах" то что в WPF реализуется минут за 5 или 10, невольно понимаешь всю мощь и те возможности, которые эта технология предоставляет.

При этом как все мирское, WPF не идеальна и не лишена недостатков, но просто плюсов все-равно больше и это факт.

Answer (score 4):

Скорее всего, это новички, которые только начинают учить .NET. Естественно, они начинают с более простой в изучении WinForms. И им не важно, что там что-то устарело, не поддерживается и т. д. Их цель - научиться писать программы.

Answer (score 2):

По поводу устарелого дизайна, я вас не понял...

По поводу поддержки Win Forms мне кажется она никуда не делась, в этом можно убедиться почитав новости про Visual Studio 2017 и .net 4.7.

Лично мои наблюдения:

WPF говорит от потрясающем быстродействии в отрисовке элементов на экране благодаря работе на DirectX. У меня комп прекрасен всем - и CPU и GPU, но, по факту, отрисовка на экране у Win Forms гораздо быстрее (GDI тоже на месте не стоит).

Контрол DataGrid на WPF крайне сырой(по крайней мере пару лет назад был).
Это самый важный контрол для представления данных вообще. Он должен быть очень универсальным, именно такой он в Win Forms, но не в WPF.
Для виртуализации данных в DataGrid (WPF)  можно использовать только виртуализацию самого источника данных через DataSource.

В Win Forms с DataGridView можно делать буквально все, что только угодно благодаря старому доброму механизму событий(CellVlueNeeded  и CellValueFormating), причем очень просто (ну и DataSource тоже на месте).

Кстати, может кто то подскажет, появился способ в DataGrid поставить програмно фокус в строку номер N не прибегая к коду в 30 строк с применением рефлексии?

На мой скромный взгляд WPF хорош для приложений где летающие и пархающие кнопочки в виде звездочек важнее всего остального.

Для бизнес-приложений важно как раз все остальное, эти приложения люди используют долгое время, по многу часов в день. Функционал их сложен и, как правило, нестандартен. Поэтому их интерфейс должен быть максимально функциональным и не оттягивать внимание на самого себя. Человек не должен уставать от пестрого и мультяшного интерфейса.

В пользу WPF скажу только, что сам принцип построения интерфейса в нем очень интересен тем, что похож на таковой в интернет-страницах. Это очень интересно, но пока сыро (до сих пор! Когда был впервые представлен WPF!?)...
И да, я не обожаю XAML.

-;)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64141/discussion-on-answer-by-------winforms--wpf-).